# How to await a useDispatch value in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my React codebase I've integrated Redux usign `react-redux` and I'm using the `useDispatch` hook to dispatch actions from my views. I just have one problem I don't have access to the updated values just after updating the store. Is there a way for me to wait for the state update to complete like `await` or something like a callback where I can execute the other code?

This is how my code looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { setCore } from "../store/global";

// the value from the store is drilled down as props
export default function Home({ instance, core }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onConnect = async () => {
    // core may have some value before but I want to clear
    console.log(core); // prints the old value
    await dispatch(setCore(null));
    console.log(core); // Need to have null here
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onConnect}>Connect</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Dispatching by default is 100% synchronous.  There's no need to wait for the dispatch itself.

However, waiting for the component's props to update is a completely different question.  Given that code, `core` will *never* update, because the definition of `onConnect` has already captured the value of `core` *at the time the function was defined*.

You may want to move that portion of the logic into a `useEffect()` hook that will trigger when the value of `core` has changed.

Comment: Okay so If I instead rely on a selector that will give me the updated value right away?

Comment: it will never be updated in the same `render` run but only in next one. is that what you mean?

Comment: If you have logic in a thunk, which has access to `getState()`, you would be able to see the newly updated state immediately after the dispatch.  In the component itself, you'd have to wait until the next render.

Comment: I come from Vue land where this is so simple, the computed property from my store is already up to date and ready for use in the next line. :(

Comment: @aks you already have the updated value, it is `null` and you're explicitly dispatching it. Just use that value manually?

Comment: yes I did that eventually. Just two places to update in case I change something in future. Of course that can be avoided by declaring a local variable above.

Comment: As I said, the new value _does_ immediately exist in the store as soon as the dispatch as done.  The difference is that with the code as written, the React component logic does not have access to that new value until it has re-rendered, and the use of hooks and closures means the code has captured the old value anyway.

Comment: Dispatching a thunk action-creator is not synchronous AFAIK.

Comment: @helper : a thunk, by itself, is 100% synchronous _unless_ you actually have some kind of async code in there.  That is, `props.dispatch`(someThunk())` will execute 100% synchronously, start to end, and it may kick off some async logic in the process (like Promises or timeouts).